# Email for user confirmation not sending in production. Rails, Heroku, Gmail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, heroku, configuration, gmail

I have looked all over Google and stackoverflow for an answer, but have been unable to find any solution. I'm trying to set up smtp emailing for user confirmation after signing up. It works fine in development. Even with MailCatcher on, it bypasses it somehow and sends to the right email from my assigned gmail.

```
config.action_mailer.raise_deliver_errors = true
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.assets.raise_runtime_errors = false
config.assets.quiet = true
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
 :address        => "smtp.gmail.com",
 :enable_starttls_auto => true, 
 :domain => 'hieu-vo.herokuapp.com',
 :port           => 587 ,
 :user_name      => 'xxxxx@gmail.com',
 :password       => 'xxxxxx',
 :authentication => 'plain',
 :openssl_verify_mode  => 'none' }
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'hieu-vo.herokuapp.com' }
```

And here is the logs when I use `heroku logs --tail`

```
2018-09-11T16:23:35.044137+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-09-11T16:23:35.043151 #4]  INFO -- : [1b2a2e36-58d4-4845-acfd-2b6fa1621d55] Started POST "/users" for 113.188.247.92 at 2018-09-11 16:23:35 +0000
2018-09-11T16:23:35.045638+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-09-11T16:23:35.045531 #4]  INFO -- : [1b2a2e36-58d4-4845-acfd-2b6fa1621d55] Processing by UsersController#create as HTML
2018-09-11T16:23:35.045793+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-09-11T16:23:35.045709 #4]  INFO -- : [1b2a2e36-58d4-4845-acfd-2b6fa1621d55]   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"cJWQmMOh4zUFre1fps03tYuYbbyA8ykZZF3djpwUpe8KWfabD5PUA8ZaC4VQ8VmF9nGVNrxUOomPCRpsKJk7aQ==", "user"=>{"email"=>"mailtest@test.com", "name"=>"hello"}, "commit"=>"Send to me"}
2018-09-11T16:23:35.050036+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2018-09-11T16:23:35.049890 #4] DEBUG -- : [1b2a2e36-58d4-4845-acfd-2b6fa1621d55]    (0.6ms)  BEGIN
2018-09-11T16:23:35.055921+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2018-09-11T16:23:35.055783 #4] DEBUG -- : [1b2a2e36-58d4-4845-acfd-2b6fa1621d55]   SQL (3.4ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("name", "email", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["name", "hello"], ["email", "mailtest@test.com"], ["created_at", "2018-09-11 16:23:35.050372"], ["updated_at", "2018-09-11 16:23:35.050372"]]
2018-09-11T16:23:35.059314+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2018-09-11T16:23:35.059167 #4] DEBUG -- : [1b2a2e36-58d4-4845-acfd-2b6fa1621d55]    (2.6ms)  COMMIT
2018-09-11T16:23:35.520783+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/users" host=hieu-vo.herokuapp.com request_id=1b2a2e36-58d4-4845-acfd-2b6fa1621d55 fwd="113.188.247.92" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=495ms status=500 bytes=1827 protocol=https
2018-09-11T16:23:35.508523+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2018-09-11T16:23:35.508354 #4] DEBUG -- : [1b2a2e36-58d4-4845-acfd-2b6fa1621d55] UserMailer#registration_confirmation: processed outbound mail in 447.9ms
2018-09-11T16:23:35.517607+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-09-11T16:23:35.517469 #4]  INFO -- : [1b2a2e36-58d4-4845-acfd-2b6fa1621d55] Sent mail to nhokkonkk13@gmail.com (8.8ms)
2018-09-11T16:23:35.517699+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2018-09-11T16:23:35.517609 #4] DEBUG -- : [1b2a2e36-58d4-4845-acfd-2b6fa1621d55] Date: Tue, 11 Sep 2018 16:23:35 +0000
2018-09-11T16:23:35.517702+00:00 app[web.1]: From: from@example.com
2018-09-11T16:23:35.517704+00:00 app[web.1]: To: nhokkonkk13@gmail.com
2018-09-11T16:23:35.517706+00:00 app[web.1]: Message-ID: <5b97ec077d6b2_411cabc85239@ba563531-54e7-4e4c-8f59-50279af29818.mail>
2018-09-11T16:23:35.517708+00:00 app[web.1]: Subject: [MAILTO HIEUVO] SOMEONE VISIT YOUR WEBSITE!!!
2018-09-11T16:23:35.517710+00:00 app[web.1]: Mime-Version: 1.0
2018-09-11T16:23:35.517711+00:00 app[web.1]: Content-Type: text/plain;
2018-09-11T16:23:35.517713+00:00 app[web.1]: charset=UTF-8
2018-09-11T16:23:35.517715+00:00 app[web.1]: Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
2018-09-11T16:23:35.517716+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-09-11T16:23:35.517718+00:00 app[web.1]: !!!!!!mailtest@test.com TALK TO YOU: hello
2018-09-11T16:23:35.518083+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-09-11T16:23:35.517991 #4]  INFO -- : [1b2a2e36-58d4-4845-acfd-2b6fa1621d55] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 472ms (ActiveRecord: 6.6ms)
2018-09-11T16:23:35.519035+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-09-11T16:23:35.518945 #4] FATAL -- : [1b2a2e36-58d4-4845-acfd-2b6fa1621d55]
2018-09-11T16:23:35.519131+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-09-11T16:23:35.519042 #4] FATAL -- : [1b2a2e36-58d4-4845-acfd-2b6fa1621d55] Errno::ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 25):
2018-09-11T16:23:35.519216+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-09-11T16:23:35.519135 #4] FATAL -- : [1b2a2e36-58d4-4845-acfd-2b6fa1621d55]
2018-09-11T16:23:35.519334+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-09-11T16:23:35.519255 #4] FATAL -- : [1b2a2e36-58d4-4845-acfd-2b6fa1621d55] app/controllers/users_controller.rb:40:in `block in create'
2018-09-11T16:23:35.519337+00:00 app[web.1]: [1b2a2e36-58d4-4845-acfd-2b6fa1621d55] app/controllers/users_controller.rb:38:in `create'
2018-09-11T16:23:35.932275+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=hieu-vo.herokuapp.com request_id=f7d117e3-a805-41b3-b315-524ce64899c2 fwd="113.188.247.92" dyno=web.1 connect=4ms service=9ms status=200 bytes=143 protocol=https
```

I wonder if i was wrong with configuration, but in my local machine it still work fine.so it might be a users problem with heroku.
Many thank!

Comment: You don't seem to have set the from address correctly as its being sent from `from@example.com`. GMail does not allow incorrect from addresses as an anti-spamming measure.

Comment: Is that configuration set in `config/environments/production.rb`?  Your error `Errno::ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 25):` seems to show that the configuration it is attempting to use is incorrect.

Comment: @RockwellRice Yes it all configuration I set it in `config/environments/production.rb`, can you give me some hint for config ? Thank you very much.

Comment: I always had a problem with gmail and Heroku.  Even though my configuration was correct it will still get denied.  I ended up using sendgrid, the comment below recommends mandrill.  I am not going to recommend a service, but I will say I had to move away from gmail because I could not get it to work even with a correct configuration.

Comment: @RockwellRice Oh, Thank you for your help :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this youtube video youtube.com/watch?v=INPqBOerfTw&t=63s

I prefer to use mandrill app instead of gmail 
https://mandrillapp.com/login/?referrer=%2F

```
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
      :address => "smtp.mandrillapp.com",
      :port => 587,
      :domain => 'www.xyz.com',
      :user_name => 'xyz',
      :password => 'xxx',
      :authentication => :plain,
      :enable_starttls_auto => true 
  }
```